# Python reshaping a list of strings based on delimiter

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have pipe delimited data being returned from a Rest API call:

```
data = ['Bob|37', 'Eric|40']
```

I extracted the header info from the first "line" and split it into a list:

```
column_list = ['Name','Age']
```

I am trying to read this into a pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(data,columns=column_list)
```

Unsurprisingly it's complaining about the data being in the wrong shape

> "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (2, 2)"

What's the best way to split the strings within the data list to be able to load it in the dataframe?

Comment: there might be a better panda-specific way, but `[row.split('|') for row in data]` is how I'd do it in pure python

Comment: Thanks @Hamms This worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = ['Bob|37', 'Eric|40']

df = pd.Series(data).str.split('|', expand=True)
df.columns = ['Name', 'Age']
print df

   Name Age
0   Bob  37
1  Eric  40
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative one-liner solution (using [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)) function:

```
In [20]: df = pd.Series(data).str.extract(r'(?P<Name>.*?)\|(?P<Age>.*)', expand=True)

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   Name Age
0   Bob  37
1  Eric  40
```